# styled-components - how to set styles in form

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

When using `styled-components` in my React app, how do I set `FormTitle` styles like this?

**Expected Output:**
[image]

I want to do `FormTitle` and `FormDescription` are separate in the new line?

**Code snippet**: (DEMO)

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-currying-533zce?file=/src/App.js

What should I change in my code? Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Just remove `display: flex;` from `ReccuringFormRow` and wrap your description elements with e. g. a `FormDescription` component and add `display: flex;` to it.

Comment: thanks, I will do it [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6429774/phil)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Phil's solution, or you can add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to ReccuringFormRow and `width: 100%;` to ReccuringFormHeaderCell.